# How to deploy a pre-populated data volume from a Docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, volumes

I have a docker-compose application consisting of several Docker containers. I build and archive the component Docker container images into a custom Registry with kaniko in GitLab-CI, and one of the artefacts of the system is a generated docker-compose YAML file that refers to the built images and can be used to bring up the system from the precise set of container images. Some of the images are third-party from other registries.

An additional artefact I need to deploy is a pre-populated data volume. This contains all of the initial configuration files needed by the containerized services in my application. The contents of this is tightly coupled to the versions of my component containers. I need a way to also store this image in the Registry (or elsewhere) so that it can be automatically "installed" along with the container images and used to bring up the docker-compose set.

I'm currently pre-populating this volume manually on the target host with a script that uses a temporary container to mount the volume and `docker cp` files into the data volume. Docker-compose accesses it as an external volume. However I need to avoid doing this manually on each host and instead have it built as part of the CI process and then deployed to each host through some mechanism.

How do I move the creation of this data volume into GitLab-CI? Is there a way to store a data volume in a Docker Registry? Can I somehow create a data volume from a "blank" docker container image? Does such a thing exist?

Alternatively, I could create a special Docker container image that holds all of the initial files (or downloads them from somewhere like a git repo) and can be used to pre-populate the data volume on the target host. Is there a better way to do this?

My end goal is to have the entire application brought up from a single script, getting everything it needs from the registry, including configuration files and initial data files. Perhaps there's already an established way to do this?

Comment: Docker registries never contain volumes.  Can you store the `docker-compose.yml` file and these configuration files, but nothing else, in a Git repository instead (so it'd be a separate production-deployment repository with no actual source code)?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, my current thinking is to have them in a repo and create a one-off container that can be used to "initialise" a fresh volume on the target host. That would allow the config files to be baked into a container image that _is_ stored in the Registry, as a kind of workaround. Thanks for confirming that Registries cannot contain volumes - that's a real shame but it is what it is.

Comment: One thought I had - Ii there a way to export a volume into some kind of single file that can be freely moved around and then restored into a volume on another machine? I suppose the contents can be just tar'ed up and then untar'ed inside a fresh volume, but I'm wondering if there's another way to do it, sort of like how VM volumes can be exported and moved between machines and VM software too, as "disk images".

Comment: The Docker documentation includes [a manual backup and restore process for named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) but it's not especially integrated.